# How to have 3 divs aligned up next to each other so that they are in between a bottom and top div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want 3 divs to be aligned up next to each other so that they are in between a bottom and top div. When floating all 3 divs to the left they are pushed to the bottom of the surrounding divs. If I float all the other divs it leaves a huge gap up top.

There is another lot of divs to the left of these divs which have css `clear:left`. When this is removed all the divs are the floated next too each other up the top of the page.

Is there an alternate route around aligning divs? or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example.

Comment: Post your code here. And maybe also an image to show how you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you need to give the bottom div `clear: left` so that it doesn't move above your three floating divs.

See [The One True Layout](http://fu2k.org/alex/css/onetruelayout/example/interactive) for an example of this done successfully.

Comment: Thank you this worked. But now a div I don't want in the line is in the line. How do I make it go below them?

Comment: @Joshua Put it after the bottom div?  Or any number of other things, depending on the details of your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have anything against a responsive css framework like Bootstrap, but if you don't mind using it (or some of it's css):

```css
.top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.middle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: dotted;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
.col-md-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.col-md-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="top col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
</div>
<div class="middle col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="middle col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="middle col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="bottom col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

`box-sizing: border-box;` is just to prevent the border to overflow the last `div` to the next row.